# Get existing arabic data from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, unicode

My boss asked to use an old SQL Server database and build a new application. When I open it, I found that all the Arabic data appear like this

http://i60.tinypic.com/14lraee.png

Firstname    |

---

ÚÌæØÚÌæØ     |

Èä ÍãíÏÉ |

ÈæÒÇäÉ   |

ÈæÔÑæÑ   |

the column type is already `nvarchar`

The old application use the same database and retrieve normally all the data arabic and non arabic i dont have the code source of this old application

How can I convert the existent data to appear normally ?

I tried  both SQL command like

```
SELECT UNICODE(@nstring)
```

or

```
NCHAR(UNICODE(@nstring))
```

and C# convert method like

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/49c55ea4-83c4-4b3b-81ef-d3a54ddf919e/how-do-i-convert-utf8-format-to-unicode-format?forum=netfxbcl

I tried open it with SQL server management studio i tried changing character set , i tried changing the Collection SET but no luck !

Comment: Can you provide a better question.  I can't understand the issue.

Comment: Sorry i can't provide print screen image yet

Comment: but the question is in old application use the same database and retrieve all the date correctly i tried every thing but i can't retrive arabic data HELP

Comment: How are you printing/showing/displaying the `first name`.  Most likely the data is correct in the DB, but you are manipulating incorrectly.  Need to see some code.

Comment: @RichardSchneider  data in sql serevr http://i60.tinypic.com/14lraee.png old application using the data http://i57.tinypic.com/mifiap.png ,me i linked datagriedview to datasource using visual studio 2013

Comment: I tried open with SQL server management studio i tried changing character set  , i tried changing the Collection no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your clues, I am guessing that the strings in the database are **NOT** Unicode, but are encoded as some `Code Page`, perhaps [Code Page 1256 Windows Arabic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195058.aspx)

If this is the case you then have to [Convert Between Legacy Encodings and Unicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488003.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
  string data = File.ReadAllText("d.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256"));
            File.WriteAllText("d.txt", data, Encoding.UTF8);
            string data2 = File.ReadAllText("t.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-6"));
            File.WriteAllText("t.txt", data, Encoding.UTF8);
```